# Need some revision on this code.

Tags: java, oop, accessor

Help, I need some revision on this code. How do I get the values of 65 and 106 without removing it from  Exercise3 myExer3 = new Exercise3(65,106);

Base Class:

```
public class Exercise3 {

private int Voltage;
private int Resistance;




public void setVoltage(int temp){
   if (Voltage == 65)   
   Voltage = temp;
}

public void setResistance(int temp){
      if (Resistance == 106 )    
      Resistance =106;       
}


public int getVoltage (){
        return (Voltage);
}

public int getResistance(){
return(Resistance);
}



}
```

Test Class:

```
 public class Test_Excercise3 {
    public static void main(String []args){


 Exercise3 myExer3 = new Exercise3(65,106);

System.out.println("Voltage: "+myExer3.getVoltage());
System.out.println("Resistance: "+myExer3.getResistance());
System.out.println("Current : "+    (myExer3.getVoltage()/myExer3.getResistance()));


}
}
```

So that I could get the result of 0.61 Ohm's or the Current.

Comment: Add a parameterized constructor to your Exercise3.

Comment: @ShadowDroid yes, But I dont have any Ideas yet how to make a constructor. new to programming

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: Then you should Google search?

Comment: @BlackHusky go through the link provided by Sajan...understand what constructor are...then implement it in your code..If you get error then edit question by the way welcome to JAVA programming

Comment: For floating point (0.61 Ω) use `double` instead of `int`. (In general int is better though.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to the Excercise3 and correct setters, also do conversion to (double) of the result.

```
public class JavaApplication27
{

    public static class Exercise3
    {

        private int voltage;
        private int resistance;

        public void setVoltage(int v)
        {
            voltage = v;
        }

        public void setResistance(int res)
        {
            resistance = res;        
        }

        public int getVoltage()
        {
            return voltage;
        }

        public int getResistance()
        {
            return resistance;
        }

        public Exercise3(int v, int res)
        {
            setVoltage(v);
            setResistance(res);
        }

        public double getCurrent() //helper method :)
        {
            return (double) getVoltage() / getResistance();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Exercise3 myExer3 = new Exercise3(65, 106);

        System.out.println("Voltage   : "    + myExer3.getVoltage());
        System.out.println("Resistance: "    + myExer3.getResistance());
        System.out.println("Current   : "    + ( (double) myExer3.getVoltage() / myExer3.getResistance())); // Since resistance and voltage are int's, the result of int/int division is int. To get a double) result use (double) :).
        System.out.println("Current   : "    + myExer3.getCurrent()); //you may also use helper method to calculate current
        System.out.format( "Current   : %.2f", myExer3.getCurrent() ); // to get .61 must use formatter
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Voltage   : 65
Resistance: 106
Current   : 0.6132075471698113
Current   : 0.6132075471698113
Current   : 0.61
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs a constructor:

```
public class Exercise3 {
    private int voltage;
    private int resistance;
    public Exercise3(int voltage, int resistance) {
        this.voltage = voltage;
        this.resistance = resistance;
    }
    ...
}
```

For more information, consult the [Java Tutorials on providing constructors for your classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).